# Find the set of values of x for which f^-1(x)g(x) is not defined.

Tags: functions

Functions $f$ and $g$ are defined by:

$f(x) = 2\cdot \sin(x)$ for $-\frac{1}{2}\pi≤x≤\frac{1}{2}\pi$ and
$g(x) = 4-2x^2$ for $x ∈ ℝ$

Find the set of Values for which $f^{-1}g(x)$ is not defined.

Is there enough information for this question? Because I don't know how to start... any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The range of $f$ is $[-2,2]$ and this is the domain of $f^{-1}$. So you have to find out when the inequality $-2 \leq g(x) \leq 2$ is not satisfied.

Comment: When g(x) is less than -3 and more than 3, right?

Comment: @RodinAkrami You have to find out when $g(x)>2$ or $g(x) <-2$. The answer is $x \in (-\infty, -\sqrt 3) \cup ((\sqrt 3 ,\infty)$.

Comment: Thank you but a question- why is there two open brackets around sqrt(3) , ∞ ?

Comment: @RodinAkrami Sorry, that was a typo.